# Get-SPOSite how to get all sites on my tenant with a Sensitivity label = Highly Confidential?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Get-SPOSite how to get all sites on my tenant with a Sensitivity label = Highly Confidential?

The Powershell command Get-SPOSite gets all sites on my Office 365 tenant. How could I filter all site with a sensitivy label?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can filter by these properties: Owner, Template, LockState, Url using Get-SPOSite.

Sensitivity label property is not available.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Get-SPOSite?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-ps